# how to display UITabBar custom items in French

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using a `UITabBarController` in my app . I used custom items like "more" . When I change the iPhone language to French, the item stay "more" and not "autre" . I have the same problem with `UINavigationController` ,

What should I implement in my app for appearing the correct text when I switch between different languages